# Inheritance/design advice in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, hierarchy

Before I begin, I should probably mention that this sort of thing should probably have been implemented using the Core Data framework, but that is out of the question now.

We have data objects that are retrieved from a web service, and I'm trying to build a hierarchy for them, but I'm struggling.

I figured my base class should be called DataEntity, and defines an abstract property called EntityId and implements the hash method based on the entityId.

Any object retrieved from the web service can be implemented in one of two ways: By passing an NSDictionary to an entity, and letting it use that as its data source, or by passing the dictionary to an entity and letting it initialise its own data members from the dictionary.  I have called these two types of entities DictionaryBackedDataEntity and ConcretedDataEntity.  So my hierarchy would then be:

```
DataEntity -> DictionaryBackedDataEntity  
           -> ConcreteDataEntity
```

Then, consumers of this package/framework would only really care about the data members that are available to it, so I have created a protocol for each data type retrievable from the interface.  So, for example, I could have a  and an  protocol, and these would have the data members that the DataEntity should expose.

So then, my hierarchy would look like this:

```
DataEntity -> DictionaryBackedDataEntity -> DictionaryBackedPerson <Person>
                                         -> DictionaryBackedAnimal <Animal>
           -> ConcreteDataEntity         -> ConcretePerson <Person>
                                         -> ConcreteAnimal <Animal>
```

Now, to be honest, I'm not sure whether I should be doing the above, or something like the below:

```
DataEntity -> PersonEntity      -> DictionaryBackedPerson
                                -> ConcretePerson
           -> AnimalEntity      -> DictionaryBackedAnimal
                                -> ConcreteAnimal
```

In the above, PersonEntity and AnimalEntity would be abstract classes, and so instances would either be DictionaryBacked or Concrete instances.

Does anyone have any experience or recommendations on how I should approach this?  I seem to be going around in circles and can't settle on a decision...

Regards,
N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have a single class `DataEntity` that stores it's property values in a dictionary? I think you probably don't need (and probably shouldn't require) to differentiate between `ConcreteDataEntity` and `DictionaryBackedDataEntity`.

```
@interface DataEntity
@property ( nonatomic, retain ) NSMutableDictionary * properties ;
@end

@implementation DataEntity
@synthesize properties ;

@end

@interface Animal : DataEntity
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger numberOfLegs ;

-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    if (( self = [ super init ]))
    {
        self.properties = dict ;
    }

    return self ;
}
@end

@implementation Animal

-(void)setNumberOfLegs:(NSNumber*)n
{
    [ self.properties setValue:n forKey:@"numberOfLegs" ] ;
}

-(NSNumber*)numberOfLegs
{
    return [ self.properties valueForKey:@"numberOfLegs" ] ;
}

@end
```

As a start...
You can save yourself some typing by using some of the more dynamic features of Obj-C here...
Look here: https://github.com/davedelong/Demos/tree/master/DynamicStorage

Comment: (if you use the dynamic properties stuff, you won't have to write your own setters/getters for each property.. Use the `@dynamic` keyword instead of `@synthesize`)

Comment: Ah I see, that DynamicStorage project looks interesting.  The main reason for the Concrete vs DictionaryBacked implementations was because one is more efficient than the other depending on its use.  For example, the Concrete implementations are faster at retrieving the data once created, but slower to create.  This is because some of the data in the dictionary requires substantial formatting/processing before it can be returned as Cocoa/C types, and I wanted both implementations available (so the framework could decide which implementation is more suitable based on the scenario).

Comment: you are mentioning efficiency...are you talking for performance reasons?  Are you dealing with thousands of objects at a time?  If not, you may be pre-maturely optimizing your code.

Comment: Hi fregas, probably not thousands, but potentially hundreds... I'd say a maximum of 1000 per call (but calls can be quite frequent).  I do have a habit of trying to optimize prematurely, so I may just try and focus on getting the functionality in there first.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely would NOT create the inheritance hierarchy you mentioned.  You want to create inheritance based on the behavior of the class, not the underlying implementation for its internal data.  You will end up with a class explosion as you add more classes that inherit from those bases and/or add more base implementations.  Imagine you later have 3 types of base classes, one using the dictionary, one getting its dictionary passed in but using properties and fields, and a 3rd that uses another object or xml document or something.  Then if you needed Person, Animal and Thing classes, you'd end up with 9 different classes total.  DictionaryBackedPerson, ConcreteBackedPerson, ObjectXmlBackedPerson, etc. etc.

I would make one base class.  Make it always have its own properties, but the ability to dynamically populate them using a dictionary if its passed, or vice versa as nielsbot mentioned.  You could loop over a dictionary and call matching property names to set the values if needed.

Comment: btw--there's a method that exists for this scenario: `- (void)setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)keyedValues` (see `NSKeyValueCoding.h`)

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying - for every data type I have, I'm going to have to create x number of classes, and that's going to end up being a lot of work.  I'd still like to have two different implementations, as both have different advantages, but evidently people don't seem keen on this.  Don't class clusters exist to achieve this sort of scenario, where different implementations can be used in different scenarios?

Comment: If you need two separate implementations, I would see if there is a way to use composition or the strategy pattern for that, possibly mixed with some objective-c dynamism/reflection.  Maybe the base class could accept an object that has the strategy for how to store the internal data.  Any child class would then have the same option, without having 2 different versions.  Stil, my opinion is that all classes should just store their data in their own fields/properties, not store them in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with either approach from the information you have provided. But there are two schools of thought from what I can see.

The first is to take a technical approach which is your first example where you use *DictionaryBackedDataEntity* and *ConcreteDataEntity*. This is where your classes are representing how things have been implemented. I've seen a lot of this approach and generally speaking I'm not really a fan. Once your code gets larger and involved more classes this approach can have problems with clarity because it does not represent the application domain, but the implementation domain. ie. you end up with many (hundreds even) classes all built around their implementations, making it hard to discern what they are doing for your program.

The second approach (*PersonEntity* and *AnimalEntity*) is I think a more practical approach because it talks about your applications context and simply by looking at the names you immediately understand what they are for. In code, simplicity and clarity make for faster development and easier maintenance.

But the real truth I think is that you are likely to need a mix of both approaches in your code base. Often you need to develop small and abstract classes which don't necessarily manifest in your problem domain directly, but go a long way towards providing infrastructural code that supports other classes. These are good candidates for naming based on their technical aspects. Often too, this is code that can be split out to a separate project and built as a framework for use across multiple applications.

Finally, which design you choose will also come down to implementation code as well. For example, depending on the internals of your entities, you might be able to go with the first approach, but modify it so that that *Person* and *Animal* are categories on *DataEntry* rather than another layer of classes.

My final piece of advice would be to not get too hung up on which to do. Pick the one that feels the most comfortable to you and go with it. If at a later stage it's proves to be less that optimal for some reason, you can refactor to the other design. If nothing else, you will learn a bit about how you relate to code.

Comment: Hi Drekka, thanks for the advice! I'm admittedly a very inexperienced developer, and whilst I'm trying to learn and read everything I can find to do with design, I hadn't really considered whether I was designing around the implementation or the application domain, so this has really helped.  I'm leaning towards the second approach too, and your response has helped to firm up my resolve.  I am finding more and more that my design comes to depend on my implementation, but I had always thought it should be the other way around, in an ideal world...?